# How much strategic depth is there in Quarriors?

Tags: quarriors

I've played Quarriors a few times and I love Dominion.  The one game of Quarriors that I won, I just happened to roll my monsters attack side up many times in a row, I didn't make any coherent plans nor perform any tactical countering of my opponents.  This has me worried about the lack of depth in Quarriors.

How much depth is there to Quarriors?  Do good players analyze a board and come up with good, kingdom-specific combos?  How often do you pass up buys for the most expensive cards for something that better fits in your deck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not much.** The game is won or lost on creatures. The problem is, those creature dice usually only have a 50%-67 chance of coming up as a creature. It is quite possible to have the better dice bag, and just lose because of poor dice rolls.

With only one buy, the best purchase is usually obvious. Since most spells don't gain you glory and creatures that score also allow you to cull your weak starting dice, you are usually best off buying the most costly creature you can get. The most costly creature usually scores the most Glory, and usually has higher defense and attack power. Many times, whomever gets an early 8 Quiddy starting roll and can buy the Dragon or other 3-4 Glory creature first will usually win.

The game is usually pretty short. This is especially true of the 4 player game, where the game ends on 12 glory. This doesn't give the dice bags much time to develop a strategy.

The Advanced and Expert rules on page 10 of the [newest rule book](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/quarma/QuarmageddonRulebook.pdf) do add some important strategic changes. With the Advanced rule, you can buy two dice per turn, that makes you have to decide on multiple smaller quicker scores (less risk of not rolling a creature), or bigger creatures that are more likely to survive. The Expert rules require you to cull the creature that scores. This rule makes the game take longer, and gives dice bag strategies more time to develop.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is quite a lot of luck, there's definitely strategy involved.

After playing probably a hundred games (at lunch time and mostly 2 player) we've noticed different play-styles. One of us tends to start off well but get bogged down. The other often starts slow but storms home at the end. This can't be put down to just luck.

The particular cards that are in play have to be analyzed to discover what will work best. This is what makes it a fun game (for us). trying to figure out what will work well **this** time.

Also note, we played the Advanced variant.

Comment: Advanced variant is the only way to go. 2 buys, and give up creatures to score them. This makes long-term engine decks viable, and multiple cheaper purchases work. Otherwise creatures decide the game entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Quariors is very luck driven.  Some people like to describe it as "luck squared" because you have the draw from the bag, and then the roll of the dice.  In Dominion you are at least guaranteed to see your new cool card sooner or later, in Quariors it could just keep rolling quidity.
The designer claims that the luck evens out throughout a game, but i find this very much not true.  Quariors lead snowballs more than any other game i have ever played.  This is a trait partially taken from Dominion, but because you score points and cull with the same action the problem is severely increased. This is also compounded by the fact that other players are playing "defense" against you, so they will keep each other down, as the runaway leader keeps running away and completely blocking the opposition.
What it finally leads to is a few early rolls deciding the entire game